# How safe is it to use PhpStorm's refactoring commands

Tags: php, phpstorm, automated-refactoring

I have some PHP code that is does not have good test coverage and is not easily testable in its current state. If I use commands from the [refactor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/refactoring-source-code.html) menu of PhpStorm, and make no other changes, how sure can I be that this won't change the behaviour of my application?

How safe are other automatic refactoring tools?

My understanding is that these tools will apply static analysis and could only cause changes to behaviour if the application does something very weird like depending on the output of debug_backtrace()

Comment: Keep in mind that refactoring only thinks of the code you have right now. If you were making code with more in mind, and you took a break to refactor, it'll probably make changes in a function that was not yet finished, and you'll have to revert to add your changes.

Comment: 1) When you refactoring something, you will have some scope options  (just code, or also include usages from commented code .. or even strings that have that class/method/variable name in it etc) 2) You can always Preview your possible changes (to be more precise -- all places of your current code where IDE will make such refactoring) as well as exclude certain lines from it before actually executing it 3) If you Save before and after doing refactoring (so editor buffer has no pending changes to be saved) you can revert all changed files back from Local History functionality

Comment: *"My understanding is that these tools will apply static analysis"* -- That's correct.

Comment: @LazyOne I know I can examine the changes before I commit and deploy to production, the question is about how safe it would be to deploy blindly to production **if I know that the only changes made to the code were the result of applying a refactor command**. It's possible that I will miss something important when reading the diff.

Answer (score -1):

The (overly) simple answer is it's no better or worse than manually refactoring.

*If you have good tests then it's safe. If you don't then it's not.*

I would say do not do any refactoring without having unit tests for each function being refactored. Refactoring should not break unit tests, if it does then you haven't refactored it, you've changed it.

I have been bitten by PhpStorms refactoring tools in weird ways in the past, even resulting in broken syntax. But, that was a long time ago, the tools have moved on, and it's always easy to go back a step if you're methodically committing changes to your SCM.

Comment: It's often impossible to write tests without doing some refactoring first. Some code isn't even in functions, it's just executed at the time the PHP file is included.

Comment: Dealing with legacy code is always challenging, but what I said is still true. Refactoring automatically or manually, will be risky without the ability to check that the code still does the same thing after you've worked on it. You need to weigh that risk against the benefits of refactoring (better tests, easier maintainability, happier developers). If you want advise as to which to go for, I'd use the tools. You can extract variables, methods, all sorts of things very quickly, giving you more time to check the right thing has happened. Take your time. Commit often.